# condition if two checkboxes are checked doesn't work in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two radio groups. I wish to put a condition where if pRange is checked (val=pRange)  and periodType value is 'one', 'two' or 'three', it displays a div called message. but my js code below doesn't seem to work. Any help is much appreciated.

```
$("input[name$='periodType']").change(function() {
        var grpname = $(this).val();
        var pname = $("input:radio[name='mainPeriod']:checked").val();
        if (((grpname == "one") || (grpname == "two") || (grpname == "three")) && (pname=="pRange")) { 
                alert( pname + ' gname= ' + 'yes'); $('.message').show; 
        }
        else { 
                alert( pname + ' gname= ' + 'no'); 
        }
 });
```

GROUP 1

```
<input type="radio" name="mainPeriod" id="pRange" val="pRange" />
<input type="radio" name="mainPeriod" id="pHour" val="pHour" />
<input type="radio" name="mainPeriod" id="pDay" val="pDay" />
<input type="radio" name="mainPeriod" id="pWeek" val="pWeek" />
<input type="radio" name="mainPeriod" id="pMonth" val="pMonth" />
```

GROUP 2

```
<input type="radio" name="periodType" val="one" />
<input type="radio" name="periodType" val="two" />
<input type="radio" name="periodType" val="three" />
<input type="radio" name="periodType" val="four" />
<input type="radio" name="periodType" val="five" />

<div class="message" style="display:none;">Message</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Whipped up a quick fiddle [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qjFuB/1/)

your radio values are written as val="" not value="" don't know if that was just for the test or in your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the console of your values

```
var grpname = $(this).val();
var pname = $("input:radio[name='mainPeriod']:checked").val();
```

The both return on/off only which is causing the issue.  What you need to get is the .attr('val') so you can check the values

```
var grpname = $(this).attr('val');        
var pname = $("input:radio[name='mainPeriod']:checked").attr('val');
```

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/B9GyV/